# How can I refresh the contents of multiple variables in a Tkinter GUI on a timer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a live weather tracker using Tkinter. I have all of the components except it doesn't update live.

I tried to resolve this with `.after()` but as I don't have functions to set my variables, it is not feasible. Is there a better way to do this or do I need to redesign my program to use functions?

And even re designing to use functions, I can't see how i'd be able to update variables without resorting to a global namespace... is there something I'm missing?

```
# imports
from foo import foobar

# access API key
owm = foobar123546242323

# create window and set title and size
master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Weatherman")
master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

# gets user location
def get_loc():
    location = sd.askstring("Input","What's your location? Format as City, Country",parent=master)
    location = location.strip()
    return location

# gets weather object
def get_weather_obj(location):
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(location)
    return observation.get_weather()

def get_detail(obj):
    weather = obj.get_detailed_status()
    return weather

def main():
    # gets information
    location = get_loc()
    weather = get_weather_obj(location)
    details = get_detail(weather)

    # gets temperature values
    temperature_values = weather.get_temperature('fahrenheit')
    high_temp = temperature_values['temp_max']
    current_temp = temperature_values['temp']
    low_temp = temperature_values['temp_min']

    # creates label at top of screen
    loc_label = tk.Label(master, text="Current weather for %s" % (location), font=("Helvetica", 50))
    loc_label.pack(padx=15,pady=15)

    # places temperature in GUI
    temp_label = tk.Label(master, text="The current temperature is %s, the low is %s, and the high is %s" % (current_temp, low_temp, high_temp), font=("Helvetica", 40))
    temp_label.pack(padx=15,pady=15)

    # place details in GUI
    details_label = tk.Label(master,text="Outside, it looks like %s." % (details),font=("Helvetica", 40))
    details_label.pack(padx=15,pady=15)

    # DEBUG
    print(get_detail(weather))

# run app
main()

# idk what this does but it goes at the end
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What’s wrong with using global variables? Roughly speaking, you need to use classes or you need to use global variables.

Comment: @BryanOakley Could you elaborate on an OOP approach? I was an idiot and didn't learn Tkinter from that angle and don't understand it too well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using tkinter variables. Unlike normal Python variables, tkinter can check when these are changed:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def a():
    v.set('a')

def b():
    v.set('b')

v = tk.StringVar()
root = tk.Tk()
Label(root, textvariable=v).pack()
Button(root, text='a', command=a).pack()
Button(root, text='b', command=b).pack()
mainloop()
```